# reading data from firebase using react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

below is the constructor function for my App.js file.

The .Auth function is working fine.....in that when a user auth changes then the function "onAuthStateChanged" runs.
However, when I update the Profile collection in firebase (manually using web GUI), the console does not log anything.  The Profile collection is the only child collection I have in my FB database.
Can anyone help me debug this? Thanks

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //initialize firebase
    if (!Firebase.apps.length) {
      Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
    Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
    Firebase.database()
      .ref('Profile/')
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code was correct....I just hadnt set the database rules in Firebase

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```